# How to make a random value stay for 1 iteration in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to be able to check my answer against the random value generated but when I type my answer in a cell and hit enter the random value changes and the verifier cell thus always shows 0 which stands for wrong (and 1 stands for right answer). Also, I don't want to freeze the random number forever but only for 1 iteration or 1 refresh. I am using Randbetween(1,1000) to generate the random numbers. Please help providing a solution for this and its ok to use another cell that stores that random value for 1 iteration.
Eg. (please see the image)  here random number generator is in the 1st ("Square") column; I type my answer in the 2nd ("Answer") column and the 3rd ("Verify") column verifies using simple formula that =if((1st Column)^2=(2nd Column),1,0).

[image]

Comment: Would a vba solution work for you?  If so then UDF similar [to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70724535)  would work

Answer (score -1):

Per the Microsoft documentation on the RAND function in Excel,

"If you want to use RAND to generate a random number but don't want the numbers to change every time the cell is calculated, you can enter =RAND() in the formula bar, and then press F9 to change the formula to a random number. The formula will calculate and leave you with just a value."

Comment: Hey, thanks for the efforts and I tried this but it is not working. Also, I don't wish to have a static value but for 1 iteration that is as if I somehow want the refresh to alternate working that is every second time the refresh shouldn't happen.