# Excel: To create a Boolean Counter function that refreshes itself like the Rand() function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I lack the knowledge of VBA so need help to create a function counter that works as follows:

```
int ctr = 1;

ctr = ctr + (-1)^ctr;

print ctr;
```

Here I want this function [written in C++ style above] to run in excel and whenever the sheet is editted or F9 is pressed, it gets refreshed/recalculated automatically just like Rand() function refreshes itself.
If such a task can be done without VBA then please enlighten me on that part too. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two main points in writing  a UDF like this

1. Use [Application.Volatile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.volatile) to force the UDF to recalc every sheet recalc
2. Declare`ctr` as [Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement) so it retains its value between calls

Something like

```vb
Function My_Func() 
    Static ctr As Integer
    Application.Volatile 
    ctr = ctr + (-1)^ctr
    My_Func = ctr
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @chris neilsen this is exactly what I wanted! I'm so happy to see this obstacle solved :).  I'm new here so couldn't upvote right now but will in future once reputation is threshold is reached. But despite that I'm feeling so grateful to you, thanks once again :).

Comment: Glad to help.  You can accept (click the tick) if you want to

Comment: Thanks again!, did not know about this either :P. (Readily) Accepted the tick :).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to insert a formula in a cell like this:
=E38+(-1)^E38
where E38 is a cell selected such as your ctr

Comment: Ya, I thought about this but such a thing is not possible directly in excel as the value won't be updated in the original value that is overwrite can't happen